# Delegate method not updating table view data in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I’m trying to use a delegate method to update `UITableView` data when a certain event occurs, but the table view is not updating. I have a custom class Engine that generates a request and updates an array of `Course` objects. I’ve set the `TopicViewController` as the delegate for the Engine instance, and implemented the `didAddCourse` method to reload the table view data. However, the table view is not showing the updated data. What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Also on main `ViewController` it works well. While with `TopicViewController delegate?.didAddCourse()` in Engine gets triggered but `func didAddCourse()` {} in `TopicViewController` don't.

```
import UIKit

TableViewController.swift

class TopicViewController: UITableViewController, EngineDelegate {
    
    let engine = Engine()
    
    func didAddCourse() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Reload the table view data to reflect the changes made to the courses array
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            // Stop the cell animation (if any)
            self.stopCellAnimation()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        engine.delegate = self
    }
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController, EngineDelegate {
    
    let engine = Engine()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        engine.delegate = self
       
    }
    
    
    func didAddCourse() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

EngineController.swift:

```
protocol EngineDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didAddCourse()
}

class Engine {
    weak var delegate: EngineDelegate?
func addCourse(name: String, content: String) {
            let separatedContent = content.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            
            courses.append(Course(name: name, description: "" ,topics: []))
            for topic in separatedContent {
                courses[courses.endIndex - 1].topics.append(Course.Topic(subTopics: [], topicName: topic))
            }
            delegate?.didAddCourse()
        }
        
        func addTopic(content: String) {
            let separatedContent = content.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            
            for topic in separatedContent {
                courses[requestedCourseIndex].topics[requestedTopicIndex].subTopics.append(Course.Topic.SubTopic(subTopicName: topic, subTopicBody: ""))
            }
            let topics = courses[requestedCourseIndex].topics[requestedTopicIndex].subTopics.count
            print(topics)
            delegate?.didAddCourse()
        }
        
}
```

I'm trying to update the table view data when a course or topic is added using the `Engine` class.
To do this, I have implemented the `didAddCourse` method in `TopicViewController`, which should be called by the `Engine` class when a course or topic is added. Inside `didAddCourse`, I'm reloading the table view data to show the new content.
However, table view is not updating after a course or topic is added.

Comment: Your two view controllers each have their own completely separate `Engine` instances. Is that right? It’s not clear from the question whether these two view controllers are expected to both update when a course is added.

Comment: You show your Engine class as having a delegate, and when you add a course that lets your Engine notify its target view controller to update its table view. You don't show your table view data source and how it provides your model data to your table view. Edit your question to provide the code for your table view data source.

Comment: Also, as Geoff says, it is strange to have separate Engine objects for each table view if they are managing the same data. You should probably have a shared Engine object and use a broadcast method to notify view controllers that your model data has changed (the Notification Manager would be a decent choice for that sort of broadcast rather than the one-to-one notification you get from the delegate pattern.)